# How are secrets related to one's potential?

Tags: the-circle

In Science Fiction movie, *The Circle (2017)*, Eamon Bailey says to Mae:

> When we are our best selves, the possibilities are  endless. There
>   isn't a problem that we cannot solve. We can cure any disease and we
>   can end hunger, and... **Without secrets, without the hoarding of
>   knowledge and  information, we can finally realize our potential**.

How are secrets related to one's potential?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood. What he's saying is that without secrets ***between humanity*** (specifically time wasted on fripperies like patents and politics), that we as a people will enjoy technological advancement at rates that haven't been seen in modern history.

His goal is no less than utter *"transparency"* between all peoples at all times.

Comment: +1 for Valorum as I think he is correct in the first part of the answer.  As Eamon demonstrated at the end, however, it seems he only believes utter transparency is good for all other people at all times. He appears not so keen on the transparency applying to himself. :-)

Comment: @beichst - Ah well, the part where he turned into a moustache-twirling comicbook villain was a total downer. He would have been a far more compelling character had he simply been a true believer in the crap he was spouting.

Comment: Agreed. At that point it simply become another big bad corporation movie like so many others.

Comment: @beichst - Hollywood seems scared of taking risks.